# Difficulty printing one particular query in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to construct a small query which will pull data from individual fields in a DB and print them in a human readable list format (it's what the operators are used to seeing). The code I have here is far from complete but It seems to me that it should work.

```
DECLARE @PSUCARD VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @EQUIPMENT VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @T1 VARCHAR
SET @PSUCARD = 'PSU-888'
SET @EQUIPMENT = '123_POUCH'

PRINT @PSUCARD + ':'
PRINT @EQUIPMENT
PRINT ''

IF (SELECT TEMPERATURE_MAIN FROM PSU WHERE PSU.PART_ID = @PSUCARD AND     PSU.OPERATION_RESOURCE_ID = @EQUIPMENT)IS NOT NULL  BEGIN
    SET @T1 = (SELECT TEMPERATURE_MAIN FROM PSU WHERE PSU.PART_ID = @PSUCARD AND PSU.OPERATION_RESOURCE_ID = @EQUIPMENT)
    PRINT 'Temperature: ' + @T1
    --(SELECT TEMPERATURE_MAIN FROM PSU WHERE PSU.PART_ID = @PSUCARD AND PSU.OPERATION_RESOURCE_ID = @EQUIPMENT)
END
```

If I execute the code as is, @T1 returns a * rather than a value. If I remove comments from the line below I am reassured that there is indeed a value there.
I have other code very similar to this which works fine. Any ideas?

Also, I don't know if this helps in diagnosing the problem, but despite the temperature field in the DB being an INT, I get a conversion message if I try to treat @T1 an an INT.

Comment: @FelixPamittan, you beat me to it.  :-)  Perhaps you should submit as answer too and OP can mark yours if it helps him.

Comment: @Matt, Just posted an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is because you declared `@T1` as `VARCHAR` without a length. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

You should always specify a length when declaring a `VARCHAR` variable:

```
DECLARE @T1 VARCHAR(50)
```

Comment: There really should be a canonical question for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give length for `varchar` datatype else it is going to take only one character

```
DECLARE @T1 VARCHAR(50)
```